# how to show my image in array or matrix in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an array like:

```
{(0, 27): 0.0, (0, 20): 0.0, (0, 14): 0.0, (0, 7): 0.0, (0, 16): 0.0, (0, 10): 0.0, (0, 3): 0.0, (0, 28): 0.0, (0, 21): 0.0, (0, 15): 0.0, (0, 24): 0.0, (0, 17): 0.0, (0, 11): 0.0, (0, 4): 0.0, (0, 29): 0.0, (0, 22): 0.0, (0, 0): 0.0, (0, 25): 0.0, (0, 18): 0.0, (0, 12): 0.0, (0, 5): 0.0, (0, 30): 0.0, (0, 8): 0.0, (0, 23): 0.0, (0, 1): 0.0, (0, 26): 0.0, (0, 19): 0.0, (0, 13): 0.0, (0, 6): 0.0, (0, 31): 0.0, (0, 9): 0.0, (0, 2): 0.0}
```

and it is an image and I want to draw it. First how should I draw it in python opencv? I know I should use

```
cv2.imshow('M',M )
cv2.waitKey()
```

but the error is:

```
ypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

and when I change it into matrix by:

```
zas = np.asmatrix(M)


[[ {(0, 27): 0.0, (0, 20): 0.0, (0, 14): 0.0, (0, 7): 0.0, (0, 16): 0.0, (0, 10): 0.0, (0, 3): 0.0, (0, 28): 0.0, (0, 21): 0.0, (0, 15): 0.0, (0, 24): 0.0, (0, 17): 0.0, (0, 11): 0.0, (0, 4): 0.0, (0, 29): 0.0, (0, 22): 0.0, (0, 0): 0.0, (0, 25): 0.0, (0, 18): 0.0, (0, 12): 0.0, (0, 5): 0.0, (0, 30): 0.0, (0, 8): 0.0, (0, 23): 0.0, (0, 1): 0.0, (0, 26): 0.0, (0, 19): 0.0, (0, 13): 0.0, (0, 6): 0.0, (0, 31): 0.0, (0, 9): 0.0, (0, 2): 0.0}]]
```

the error is:

```
TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported
```

would you please tell me what mistake I am making?

Comment: The array that you state is actually a dictionary. What format is this dictionary in?

Comment: From where you got that dictionary ?

Comment: It's in the following format: {key:value, key:value} rather than [item1, item2, item3, item4...]

Comment: Oh! yes..you are right. now how can I change the dictionary to other data classes and how can I draw my image?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to looking for values in that dictionary to draw as image. It's simple.It hold 32 values and i hope it's a size of image is 1 by 32.
Then you can Plot like this.
I considered **a** as your dictionary.

```
a = {(0, 27): 0.0, (0, 20): 0.0, (0, 14): 0.0, (0, 7): 0.0, (0, 16): 0.0, (0, 10): 0.0, (0, 3): 0.0, (0, 28): 0.0, (0, 21): 0.0, (0, 15): 0.0, (0, 24): 0.0, (0, 17): 0.0, (0, 11): 0.0, (0, 4): 0.0, (0, 29): 0.0, (0, 22): 0.0, (0, 0): 0.0, (0, 25): 0.0, (0, 18): 0.0, (0, 12): 0.0, (0, 5): 0.0, (0, 30): 0.0, (0, 8): 0.0, (0, 23): 0.0, (0, 1): 0.0, (0, 26): 0.0, (0, 19): 0.0, (0, 13): 0.0, (0, 6): 0.0, (0, 31): 0.0, (0, 9): 0.0, (0, 2): 0.0}
In [20]: zas = np.asmatrix(a.values())
In [24]: cv2.imshow('M',zas)
In [25]: cv2.waitKey()
```

But it's not a good method to store image as dictionary. Try to maintain as a numpy array.

Comment: the program for calculating M is:                                                                                                                  for i in range(0, (height-2*5)):
        for j in range(0, (width- 2*5)):
             block = np.array(img[i:i+win, j:j+win])
             # Compute the median in each window                                 M[i,j] =np.median(block) ..................  I actually do not know how it changes to a dictionary!!!